# Add to Sandbox or How to Ask

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions, challenges, help-center

Users are constantly asking for clarification of programming puzzles. In an attempt to help new users create good challenges, I asked this question on Meta PPCG: [Things to consider when creating a programming puzzle](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5582/41912).

I've gotten some great answers, so it's time to make sure users see it when they ask a question. A link to it might be helpful in these places:

- Sandbox
- Help Center
- "How to Ask" pane on the right side of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and added the post to [our community FAQ](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1280/3808).

Let me know if you think it needs to be more prominently featured.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think users will see that before asking a question? If not, it might be a good idea to put a link in the sandbox.