# Who wins code golf if there is a tie?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

On my code golf challenge, there are two tie 24 Bytes answers.

The [first one (Excel)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173132/75908) is great because of the creativity put into it and the [second one (MATL)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173118/75908) is just skill *I think* and each one should win the "prize".

They both posted their answers on the same day - actually only 3,5 h apart from each other.

As [this question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5097/should-there-be-defaults-for-tiebreakers-in-tag-wikis) has asked the same question bevor, I can't get anything out of it as the only two answers (which are from the same user) are the complete opposite of each other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most people who post [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenges *never* accept an answer, so people are more likely to compete in the challenge. (I personally don't see how the accepted mark would change which challenges you do/don't look at though, tbh.. But I can understand the reasoning of not accepting any answers at all.)

I myself accept answers after a few weeks however (and update when a shorter one is posted later on), so I can relate to your question. I have a few challenges where two or three answers have the same byte-count. Those I personally left without an accepted mark. And I sometimes check to see if anyone made a golf to their answer and there is now a single shortest one.
Most people who accept answers on [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenges like us would accept the earliest one. So in the case of your challenge, the answers were posted at:

- Excel: October 1st, 2018 at 18:51:27
- MATL: October 1st, 2018 at 15:38:39

So in this case, the MATL answer would get the accepted check.

Alternatively, although I think your rep is currently to low for this feature, you could offer both answers a 50-bytes bounty to show your appreciation.

Whatever you choose is up to you. The general consent is to not accept [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenges, and if you do, to accept the shortest one (and earliest posted in case of a tie), as the accepted answer in your linked meta-post also states:

> If no tie-breakers are specified, or all specified tie-breakers are exhausted, the **earliest answer wins**. When determining which answer was earlier, the timestamp of the first valid edit which gave the current score counts.

Comment: Thanks mate, may I take your path of waiting for the chosen one who pass them both. But what is curious to me is the second response from @Martin Enders on the linked question: `In the case of popularity contests, if there is a tie, the latest answer wins.` What does popularity contests means - is it connected to `code-golf`?

Comment: @Hille In the past there were `[popularity-contest]` challenges as [win-condition](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/908/52210), where the answer with the most upvotes, thus most popular, would win. Those aren't really on-topic anymore in the current meta however, and most pop-con (as well as code-bowling) would usually be closed today.

Comment: Didn't know that those existed, but interesting to see all the different tags. Thanks again (ignoring the fact that 'thanks' is not desired)

Comment: One additional reason that I prefer not accepting an answer is so that people can sort by oldest or by active without the tick overriding the sort order.